# Are you supposed to type '6' with the left hand or the right hand?

Tags: typing, touch-typing

A few weeks ago, I did a Google Images search for [keyboard finger charts](http://www.google.com/images?q=keyboard+finger+charts) to see which fingers I'm supposed to be using to type which keys.  According to the charts, '6' is supposed to be typed with the right hand:

[image]

*(as shown on [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typing#Touch_typing))*

However, today I spotted a split keyboard in a store with the '6' on the left side of the split.  Indeed, an image search for [split keyboards](http://www.google.com/images?q=split+keyboards) indicates that this is the norm:

[image]

*(as shown on [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_keyboard))*

When doing touch typing "correctly", should I go with the finger charts (type 6 with my right hand), or should I go with the split keyboards (type 6 with my left hand)?

Comment: I was taught (way back when) to use my left hand, like the Natural keyboard shows. But recently while using a Dvorak typing tutor (where the number row is unchanged) it suggested that I use the right hand for the 6, which I now find *much* easier.

Comment: @fideli 6 is closer to F compared to J so why using right hand is much easier?

Comment: Based on viewing the different images and split keyboards, I believe that you are supposed to type the `6` with your right hand. I think the split keyboards put the `6` on the left side because it splits the keyboard in half more evenly (since the `6` is almost directly above the `B`). I use a split keyboard and wish they had put the `6` on the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keyboard typing methods were invented way after the layout was invented. This is really personal preference. Just like how I type the C with my index finger instead of my middle finger.

In other words, whichever it is you like. Heck, add it as a speech command if you like so that you don't have to worry about wondering which fingering to use.

Comment: I do the c with my index finger too.  And I was typing 120 WPM in the third grade, yet the teacher still insisted on 'correcting' my technique.

Comment: I type c with my index finger, x with my middle finger, z with my ring finger. And yeah, b with my **right** index finger.